# document.writing with Javascript - smarty

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I opened a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555279/smarty-javascript-interference) yesterday about javascript and smarty, so since I wasn't able to deal with the { %} tags. All the info can be found [here](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates#compiled-templates)

```
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

I am trying to put the tags inside strings as so :

```
<script id="template-download">
    for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {
        document.write('<tr class="template-download fade">');
            if (file.error) {
                document.write('<td></td><td class="name"><span>**');document.write(file.name);**
```

...

The problem is now that the last line is read partially and doens't output in my browser, but the line I put here in bold outputs litteraly in my browser. Why is that ?

Comment: What bold line? Fix your code block please and include all the code which might be affected.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Sorry the editor didn't take it into account : the bold is the strings between **..**

Comment: Don't use `document.write` and don't write HTML in JS.

Comment: @PeeHaa Yes I know but I am struggling for two days with jquery upload plugin since smarty is not able to read those tags { %} even if I wrapp smarty inside {literal} tags so I don't know what to do

Comment: Sorry Newben I still need to see all your code. It's cut off and needs to be fixed. Please fix your question.

Comment: You either want Javascript generated on the server side by PHP/Smarty, or you want to dynamically generate HTML with Javascript. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally,

I managed to make it go right as so :

{literal}

{{literal}%{/literal} for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { {literal}%{/literal}}
...

{/literal}

and so on...